# Echo and specific value in PHP from an array

Tags: php

I am a newbie to PHP and trying out some things to see they work .. I have tried lots of different attempts at this .. but no luck .. It is supposed to echo output 2 .. !!! I keep getting errors.

```
<?php

$a = array('x' => array('y' => 1, 'z' => 2, 'q' => 3,));

echo {$a['z']};//echo the value 2 from $a (tried this and it did not work.  

?>
```

Comment: try $a['x']['z'] because its a multidimensional array and without brackets:
    echo $a['x']['z'];

Answer (score 5):

Since you have an array within an array, you need to do:

```
echo $a['x']['z'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using an associative array, and your syntax is incorrect.

To get to `z` you need to go through `x`:

```
echo $a['x']['z'];
```

The curly braces syntax is only used when you want to access an array (called [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)) inside a string (which is called [variable interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation)):

```
echo "The value is: {$a['x']['z']}";
```

If you are not dereferencing a variable using the square brackets then you do not need the curly braces:

```
$value = $a['x']['z'];
echo "The value is: $value";
```

Also, you mention that you get errors. Learn what they mean and you will be able to help yourself. If you ask for help then it would also be a good idea to tell us about the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this without braces

```
echo $a['z'];
```

Or no, you have two arrays

try

```
echo $a["x"]["z"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply:

```
<?php

$a = array('x' => array('y' => 1, 'z' => 2, 'q' => 3,));

echo $a['x']['z'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You array is [multi-dimensional](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so you have to provide two indexes:

```
echo $a['x']['z']; // echoes 2
```